# Move selectors on page with webdriverio

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

**from** and **to** is "buttons" in a slider to change the from and to time.
I´m having problem how to move these buttons in webdriverio. Below is an example how i want to do it, but nothing happens.

```
let from = browser.element('#from');
let to = browser.element('#to');

var XCordinate = from.getLocation(); //gets current x position of from element
var yCordinate = from.getLocation(); //gets current y position of from element

from.moveToObject(XCordinate+20, yCordinate); //Move the element only in x
```

Answer (score 1):

Because moveToObject function just move your cursor to that cordinates, Not clicking there or taking any action on there.

You can use `buttonDown`,`buttonUp` and `moveTo`  methods of webdriverio as below :

```
browser.buttonDown(button); 
browser.moveTo(element,xoffset,yoffset); 
browser.buttonUp(button);
```

Comment: But all these: ButtonDown, buttonUp and moveTo is deprecated

Comment: Sorry about it, I was also known that but i forgot.

Comment: And actions are not supported in chrome :(